# Dataverse related tables PowerApps Canvas

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

Can anyone help me please, I am trying to retrieve data about Employee and Project from Gallery (DataSource: AssignmentDate),

My tables are connected like this: I am able to retrieve data about Project/Employee if I connect my gallery to assignemnt, but not from assignment date.

Any ideas?

[image]

I am trying to display data from connected tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you won't be able to get data about Employee and Project from AssignmentDate.

If you see in your data model your project and employee are connected to assignment.

solution, first you will have to retrieve assignment record, fields project code and emplyoee hrd.
Then you will have to do lookup function for each project and employee based on your  fields project code and emplyoee hrd

Comment: Thank you! Solved with LookUp function, thank you :)